# Force a SQL Server query to return no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
     CASE
          WHEN ([DBO].fn_WorkDays(GETDATE(), DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) = 2)
               THEN 1
     END
```

That should return 1 if the condition is true (obviously), but I want it to return nothing (no rows) if false. Instead, it's returning a null row. How do I force it to return 1 or nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have this coded it will always return a row. You could rearrange your query to put the scalar function in the where clause.

```
SELECT 1
where [DBO].fn_STRS_WorkDays(GETDATE(), DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) = 2
```

Of course, you might consider evaluating that scalar function. They are notoriously poor for performance.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
IF [DBO].fn_STRS_WorkDays(GETDATE(), DATEADD(d, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) = 2
    SELECT 1
```

Answer (score 4):

select * from dbo.table where 1=0

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, taking into account the post and not only the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `where` clause and subquery:

```
select 1
from (select [DBO].fn_STRS_WorkDays(GETDATE(),
                                    DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()) )
                                   ) as workdays
     ) x
where workdays = 2;
```

Actually, the subquery isn't necessary.  I just think `where` without `from` looks awkward.  You could write it as:

```
select 1
where 2 = [DBO].fn_STRS_WorkDays(GETDATE(),
                                 DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()) )
                                )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to actually filter your data on that criteria it **needs** to be in the WHERE clause portion of your query, not just in the column definition portion.
This may mean that you need to specify your condition twice (once in the column portion and once in the WHERE clause).